# po is not working in swift project Xcode 6 GM

Tags: swift, xcode6, lldb, xcode6gm

I recently started working on a swift project created in Xcode 6 GM, but it seems I am unable to print any variables using `po`
[image]

Any any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: probably a bug in XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on a 32-bit device?

From the Xcode 6.1 beta Release Notes:

• Expressions like expr, p, and print that are evaluated from the LLDB prompt in the debugger console will fail on 32-bit iOS devices. However, they will work on 64-bit devices and the iOS simulator. (18249931)

Comment: ahh that must be it, because i was using an iPod touch 5th gen.  But is that only for swift code, because I am able to use the debugger with objective c code

Comment: Yes, that bug only occurs when you are stopped in a frame of Swift code.